# jCarousel adding items from JSON object onclick, wont scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jcarousel

I have 4 or 5 JSON objects that are created dependent on a menu item being click, what I am wanting to do is,

1. The user clicks a menu item (Walls for example)
2. A navigation bar is show that show thumbnails of the choice of walls that are available, the navigation bar is long and thin (horizontal across the page), with jCArousel it should show 4 choices ad then on clicking the next button it should scroll to the next 4.
3. If the user then clicks Doors, the walls navigation should dissapear, the subnav (and jcarousel) should then get populated with doors.

I am not having a problem populating the jcarousel with new data, I am having a massive issue getting it to scroll once it has been repopulated.

For some reason I cannot get the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Udders/Mrsye/embedded/result/) working with the JSON object, but click floors and the doors and you should get hte GIST of what I am trying to achieve.

The function is causing a problem I believe is,

```
function mycarousel_itemAddCallback(carousel, first, last, data)
```

{
     // Simply add all items at once and set the size accordingly.

```
 console.log(data);

for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    $("#secondary ul").add(i+1, '<li><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/141x75"/></a></li>');
}

$("#secondary ul").size(data.length);
```

}

Do I need re-initializze the carousel after adding new data or something?

Answer (score 0):

From documentation:

> reload
>
> Reloads the carousel. This method is useful to reinitialize the
> carousel if you have changed the content of the list from the outside
> or want to change options that affect appearance of the carousel at
> runtime.

```
$('.jcarousel').jcarousel('reload', {
    animation: 'slow'
})
```